# How to use fmt library in the header-only mode?

Tags: c++, fmt

Having a hard time using the header-only mode of fmt library. Here is what I tried in details:
I downloaded fmt7.1.3 from https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html, only put the directory `fmt-7.1.3/include/fmt` in a directory (`[trgdir]`) and wrote a test.cpp as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/format.h>
int main() {
    fmt::format("The answer is {}.", 42);
    return 0;
}
```

Then in the terminal I use

```
gcc -I[trgdir] test.cpp
```

where gcc I defined as

```
alias gcc='gcc-10 -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc -std=c++17 -O2 '
```

I got the error goes as

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZN3fmt2v76detail7vformatB5cxx11ENS0_17basic_string_viewIcEENS0_11format_argsE", referenced from:
      _main in ccEeTo0w.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have checked this post but I still cannot solve my issue. [How to use the fmt library without getting "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56608684/how-to-use-the-fmt-library-without-getting-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x)

Comment: I recommend using a build system like CMAKE together with a package manager like vcpkg

Comment: I believe you cannot. `fmt` builds a static library. You need to add linking.

Comment: @ALX23z fmt does have a header-only version. Check the [documentation](https://fmt.dev/latest/usage.html#header-only-usage-with-cmake)

Comment: @bolov Thanks for the recommendation on the usage of build system and package manager. Definitely go that route in the future.

Comment: I think you need to put the library in directory `[trgdir]/fmt`.

Comment: Are you using literal square braces `[` and `]`? If so you´ll need to escape them on the command line.

Comment: You can also replace `gcc-10 -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc` with `g++-10`.

Comment: @Galik. Re ```[trgdir]/fmt``` Do you mean the header file is the directory ```[trgdir]/fmt/fmt/format.h```?

Comment: @rustyx Thank you for the suggestion. Just curiosity, is ``` g++-10``` an equivalent of   ```gcc-10 -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc``` or there is some tiny different? The reason I use ```gcc-10``` is I want to use new features of C++. Back to the question, with the replacement, I still got ```Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:```

Comment: No. I mean `-I[trgdir]`is prepended to your `#include`statement giving a search path of `[trgdir]/fmt/format.h` to find the file.

Comment: @Galik I see. I believe my ```fmt``` file is inside ```[targdir] ```

Comment: There is no difference, but `gcc` is a C compiler. You should use `g++` to compile and link a C++ program.

Comment: @rustyx. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to define a macro before include, like this:

```cpp
#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
#include "fmt/format.h"
```

Comment: Thank you. You save my day. Finally I can use ```fmt``` May I ask how you figure it out? because some library does not need to include ```#define**``` such as Eigen.

Comment: @Ethanabc You can find it at the very end of the `fmt/format.h` file. But, frankly saying, I don't understand why it's lacking in the official documentation.

Comment: I just installed `fmt` via `vcpkg` and I ran into this same issue. This solved it for me but I'm irritated that this is required in the first place.