# How to setup {fmt} library for Unreal Engine project?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, fmt

I'm trying to setup fmt for UE4 project, but still getting compiler errors.

Used toolchain: MSVC\14.16.27023

fmt lib is build from source.

I googled [this](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/2965) issue and undefined check macro.

```
#undef check
#include <fmt/format.h>

void test()
{
    auto test = fmt::format("Number is {}", 42);
}
```

Getting this compiler errors:
[image]

I tried this defines and this still not compile.

```
#define FMT_USE_CONSTEXPR 0
#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
```

Maybe someone managed use fmt library in Unreal Engine projects and can share some experience?

Comment: Did you try to compile without binaries? If you use the library in header-only mode, you don't need to build it or include the binaries. You need just to include the needed header file(s) after a `#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944554/how-to-use-fmt-library-in-the-header-only-mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two main problem with integrating {fmt} library in Unreal Engine.

1. global define for check macro. Some variables/function inside fmt implementation named "check". So there is a conflict.
2. Warning as errors enabled by default. So you have either disable this, or suppress specific warnings.

I ended up with this solution for my UE project. I difined my own header-wrapper

MyProjectFmt.h

```
#pragma once

#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY

#pragma push_macro("check") // memorize current check macro
#undef check // workaround to compile fmt library with UE's global check macros

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #pragma warning(push)
    #pragma warning(disable : 4583)
    #pragma warning(disable : 4582)
    #include "ThirdParty/fmt/Public/fmt/format.h"
    #include "ThirdParty/fmt/Public/fmt/xchar.h" // wchar support
    #pragma warning(pop)
#else
    #include "ThirdParty/fmt/Public/fmt/format.h"
    #include "ThirdParty/fmt/Public/fmt/xchar.h" // wchar support
#endif


#pragma pop_macro("check") // restore check macro
```

And then use it in your project like this:

SomeActor.cpp

```
#include "MyProjectFmt.h"

void SomeActor::BeginPlay()
{
    std::string TestOne = fmt::format("Number is {}", 42);
    std::wstring TestTwo = fmt::format(L"Number is {}", 42);
}
```

Also, you could create some Macro-wrapper around it to putt all your characters in Unreal Engine's `TEXT()` macro, or even write custom `back_inserter` to format characters directly to `FString`. This is easy to implement, but this is another story.